# Sum of numbers in assembler

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, sum

Sorry for my bad English! Thanks in advance for your answers.

I tried to write assembler code, which must do this (FOR EXAMPLE C++):

```
int N, a = 0;
cin >> N;
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
        a = a + i;
    }
}
cout << a << endl;
```

In other words the task sounds like this: "Find the sum of numbers that are divided into three without remainder using assembler"

I wrote this, but it is not working correctly for some reason:

```
__asm
{
    mov ecx, n
    mov eax, 0
    mov ebx, 0
    asm_for:
    add ebx, 1
        add eax, 1
        mov edx, 0
        div b
        cmp edx, 0
        JE then
        then : add a, ebx
        Loop asm_for
        mov edi, a
        mov sum, edi
}

cout << sum << endl;
```

Console shows sum of ALL number from 1 to N. But I only need sum of numbers that are divisible by three without a remainder. What did I do wrong? Thanks in advance for your answers again!

Comment: You *could* use `div` to calculate a remainder every time, or you could notice that every 3rd number is a multiple of 3 and just increment `i` by 3.  Or use a separate down-counter to do something every 3rd iteration if you don't want to optimize it into `+=3`.  Of course if you want to fully apply the as-if rule like a C compiler would, you can use the closed form for the sum of integer from 1..x where x=N/3.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I know that every third number is divided by three (3, 9, 12 and so on), but unfortunately I need to do "work" with every number. Sorry if I misunderstood you.

Comment: Next time please specify *it is not working correctly*. 
Look at the instruction `JE then`: if the remainder in edx is 0, it jumps to the label `then`. And if it is not 0, it does not jump and continues to the same label `then`.